# Can't sync saves between devices (iOS)

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have been playing on my iPhone and have Cloud save checked. Today I got my iPad and I can't get it to sync. My iPad has an older version (about 24h diff) of my saves and they don't update. I have cloud checked and have not gotten any error messages about sync failure.

Is there more to it or is it just not possible to have FA:S updated on two devices?

Comment: You should be able to play it on 2 updated devices according to the following: http://www.techtimes.com/articles/95822/20151015/fallout-shelter-update-adds-cloud-saves-new-survival-difficulty.htm

Comment: @Zissouu Yes, and it's that thing that doesn't work. Either my iPhone doesn't save to the cloud or my iPad doesn't recieve from the cloud. They just don't sync between each other.

Comment: Were you connected to the internet the last time you closed the game?