# Is it possible to transfer a game to another device?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'm assuming the answer is no, but I wanted to try anyway. I have a long-standing vault on my phone, but it's getting increasingly difficult to manage due to the small phone screen. (May or may not be related to my aging eyes as well.) I have an iPhone. Is it possible to transfer the vault/save to another device, preferably a Mac desktop, or perhaps even another iOS device like an iPad? I've got close to 200 dwellers, quite a lot of caps, tons of max level dwellers, lots of legendary blueprints, etc.

I saw [another post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/313575/cant-sync-saves-between-devices-ios) about syncing to iCloud, but I've heard there are issues with that, and I haven't tried it for fear of impacting my game.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look at your vault list, there is an option to turn on "cloud save"

[image]
[image]

If you turn this on, the next time you log in to your game center or iTunes account, you can download the games onto your new device.

Comment: While it doesn't allow transfer from my phone to my Mac (even though I have Game Center -- but Fallout Shelter doesn't exist on OSX outside of Steam at least that I've seen) it will at least allow me to transfer to a tablet so I can see what's going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The vaults are .sav files on your phone. I have an Android N device and the save file is located under `/Internal Storage/Android/data/com.bethsoft.falloutshelter/files/`, the names are `Vault1.sav` and so on (obviously, the path will be different for your iPhone, you'll have to figure that one out yourself or google for it). You can move these files between devices and that way, you can also transfer your vaults. This should work without problems between iPhone and iPad, not sure about the Mac tho.

I did the same a few years ago when switching to a new smartphone and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: You cannot in general access the file system on iOS.

Comment: @OrangeDog What? Really? iOS doesn't even allow that I access my own files? This thing really is a golden cage jesus.

Comment: @OrangeDog, but there appear to be ways: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54682/easiest-way-to-browse-iphone-filesystem

Comment: @theUg all of which either won’t work or require jailbreaking.

Answer (score 0):

The game uses Game Center so you should be able to access your vaults on another iOS device if you sign into your Apple ID and Game Center.